# how to avoid overload method when  validating different number type if be positive or zero in java?

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isNoPositive(long number) {
    return number <= 0;
}; 

public static boolean isNoPositive(float number) {
    return number <= 0;
 };
```

when every primary type added , I should add one similar method: overload the method.
but if I used base class : `Number`.  not have > 0 method but only has `intValue()`. `floatValue()`,etc.

So what I can do to avoid overload?

Comment: You could think of it this way: What if someone extended the class to complex numbers? Is `1 + i` positive?

Comment: Seems like you would be better off just checking `if (number > 0) { // do stuff...` in your code instead of making a special method for it.  Not to mention a method name like `isNoPositive` is ridiculous.  Either it's `isPositive` or `isNegative`, but `isNoPositive` sends my brain into logical backflips trying to parse what it means.

Comment: @TimPote: No. `isNotPositive` means `isNegative || isZero`.

Comment: @SLaks Then the question is `isPositive`.  Then you can feel free to use it as `!isPositive()`, and that's easy to parse.  However, trying to figure out what it means to say `!isNoPositive()` all over the place would be *maddening*.

Comment: My mean not focus on the how to judge positive, but use which way to aovid overload method .

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public boolean isNotPositive(Number val) {
    return val.longValue() <= 0 && val.doubleValue() <= 0;
}
```

<del>You do have to enumerate all of the possibilities though.</del>  You can get away with just testing for a long value or double value, since shorts and ints are covered in the scope of a long, and floats are covered in the scope of doubles.  There may be a more elegant solution, but for a few tests, it's not failing.

**EDIT:** So the original boolean OR failed when `0.1` was put through it.  I changed it to a boolean AND instead, and the results are consistent with what it should be.  It works due to the sign bit being in the same place for both long and double types.

Comment: Since 1.5, Java supports auto-boxing.

Comment: 0.1 can't pass the test.It seems val.doubleValue() <= 0 can cover all test cases. But I can't make sure of it.